# How do I build a Github API for Java, in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github, github-api

I am trying to build Github API for Java in Eclipse. 
I download the project from the link https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core and follow the readme's instructions about the build using a pom/xml file.
Then I execute the maven's command as it is described but errors occured.

### Maven commands in readme file are :

Building

The GitHub Java API is built using Apache Maven.

Run the following command to build a JAR file containing the GitHub Java API without dependencies:

```
$ mvn -f pom-jar.xml clean install
```

All-in-one

The GitHub Java API can also be built as a JAR that includes all the dependencies (Google Gson). This technique uses the Maven Shade Plugin to build an all-in-one JAR file.

```
$ mvn -f pom-jar.xml clean install -P shade
```

This happens when i execute the maven command `$ mvn package` or the command described in read me file.

```
C:\Users\panagiotis\Desktop\egit-github-master>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.mylyn.github:org.eclipse.egit.github.core:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\panagiotis\Desktop\egit-github-master\org.eclipse.egit.github.core\pom.xml
[INFO] Adding repository file:/C:/Users/panagiotis/Desktop/egit-github-master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/../../egit/org.eclipse.egit.repository/target/repository
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'egit' from location file:/C:/Users/panagiotis/Desktop/egit-github-master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/../../egit/org.eclipse.egit.repository/target/repository: No repository found at file:/C:/Users/panagiotis/Desktop/egit-github-master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/../../egit/org.eclipse.egit.repository/target/repository. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'egit' from location file:/C:/Users/panagiotis/Desktop/egit-github-master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/../../egit/org.eclipse.egit.repository/target/repository
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'egit' from location file:/C:/Users/panagiotis/Desktop/egit-github-master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/../../egit/org.eclipse.egit.repository/target/repository
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:301)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.gatherExternalInstallableUnits(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:269)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(P2DependencyResolver.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:77)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at file:/C:/Users/panagiotis/Desktop/egit-github-master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/../../egit/org.eclipse.egit.repository/target/repository.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:692)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:297)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

I am using Maven for first time so I cant find where the problem is.
Maybe I have to move `egit-github-master` folder in other specific directory or I am using the wrong commands to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone [these 3 repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide#Repositories) and import basically all of the contained eclipse projects:

- jgit
- egit
- egit-github

You build fails to resolve the target platform project, which is part of the egit repository. You should read the full [egit contributor guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide), as some more setup of your IDE is needed, before the build succeeds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to build the Api using the egit contributor guide

Comment: A new problem caused during the build concern clone failures. I posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397910/github-api-for-java-in-eclipse-failures) about this issue.